# Как правильно: "за нею" или "за ней"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, местоимения

*Душа моя рвётся

На небо **за Нею**,

Душа не живёт

Если рядом не **с Нею**.*

Можно ли так говорить? Или всё-таки правильно **за ней**?

Answer (score 4):

Так *допустимо* говорить в литературных текстах, однако если в беспредложном варианте творительного падежа (ею) выбор окончания обоснован необходимостью отличить падеж от дательного, то при наличии предлога такая мера может восприниматься излишней и не вполне естественной для обыденной речи. Но в художественных произведениях такой вариант может быть уместен.

Answer (score 0):

1. На самом деле оба варианта верны, несмотря ни на что, как и 2 вида родительного падежа:

   > Без чая

> Без чаю

и как и 2 вида винительного падежа (аккузатив и ждательный падеж):

> Ждать письмо
>
> Ждать письма (ударение на последний слог)

соответственно. Но во избежание путаницы с дательным обычно пишут и "неЮ" вместо "неЙ", и "чаЯ" вместо "чаЮ". Для рифмы может быть по-разному.